# sql databases Northwinds , pubs , AdventureWorks or some others?

Tags: sql-server-2008, northwind, adventureworks, pubs

Technology : Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Aim : Master SQL Server 2008 using Microsoft's databases

I am looking for a tutorial where I get a lot of exercises to do, so that I can master SQL Server 2008. Isn't it a good idea to choose Microsoft's databases such as Northwinds , pubs , AdventureWorks. Which one is good? Can you give me a link to exercises if you choose between the databases?

**I am focused on the set of exercises rather than tutorials. Just questions are enough . :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check these.

1) http://www.sqlcourse2.com/index.html

2) http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html

3) http://www.scribd.com/doc/3144852/SQL-Exercise

4) http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/slides/slides6.pdf

5) http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/practice-interview-question-1/

Comment: The questions are not based on Northwinds, pubs and AdventureWorks

Answer (score 2):

If you are a beginner you can start with tutorials in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp). You can first learn basics by creating your own simple database, executing queries. The standard available  DataBases which you have mentioned above will also be helpful.

1) http://www.sqlcourse2.com/index.html

2)http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/tutorial/

3)http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-commands.html

Comment: I am focused on the set of exercises rather than tutorials. Just questions are enough